# Binary operator on object with heap member

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose i have two BitArrays, every has allocated member that stores actual bits inside.

I want to implement bitwise or, and.

My try:

```
BitArray BitArray::operator &(const BitArray &other) const
{
    BitArray anded;
    anded.Initialize(this->m_Size);
    for (uint32 i = 0 ; i < this->m_Size; i++)
    {
        anded.m_Array[i] = other.m_Array[i] & m_Array[i];
    }
    return anded;
}
```

Before returning from the function destructor of anded called and all my job is lost, in addition subsequent call to destructor of assigned object will crash.

What options do i have? Create subclass of BitArray as MoveableBitArray, and overload copy constructor to move data? Any other options? Thanks.

I don't use C++11.

EDIT: for now i have no copy constructor in the class.

Comment: Have you defined a copy constructor?

Comment: You need to define a copy constructor that makes a copy of the memory allocated for your bits.

Comment: @Arkadiy , additional allocation/deallocation - costly

Comment: See the Rule Of Three.  Implementing a destructor without a copy constructor is a huge warning sign.

Comment: @molbdnilo , why not move?

Comment: @Yola If you say `BitArray a; BitArray b(a);` you still want the data in `a` to be there, don't you?  You could use a `shared_ptr` for the storage (or reference-count manually), but then  you would have to make it immutable and that also has a cost. How big are these arrays?

Comment: @molbdnilo usually 4-10 bytes.

Comment: @Yola And how many million copies per second are you making?

Comment: @molbdnilo Approximately 0.000005 and by the this this is offline calculation, so user will see nothing.

Comment: You can use move semantics and/or refcounted pointers or may be some other things. Everything is a tradeoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT: for now i have no copy constructor in the class.

Well, there's your problem. What exact behaviour are you expecting from the compiler, anyway? You returned *a copy* of your local but didn't tell it to do anything special. You certainly did not tell it to not destruct your local and then the copy later. It did exactly what you told it to do. Every variable you created, it kindly destructed for you, as the Holy Standard says it should. And when you asked it to copy your return value, it kindly did exactly that, in exactly the way it was supposed to. You did not ask it to do anything special here.

If you want to return copies of your local variables, and you need special copy behaviour, *then implement a copy constructor*. That's what it's for. How is the compiler possibly supposed to implement returning the local variable if it can't move it because it's pre-C++11 and it can't copy because so expenisve? What is the compiler supposed to do?

Edit: I did not actually pay a great deal of attention to your code, but it seems to me that you are reimplementing boost::dynamic_bitset, but worse, and in your implementation, you are reimplementing std::vector but worse. These Standard and semi-standard classes exist for a reason, and you are just duplicating their effort badly. Just use them and it will be much easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an instance to a function or return an instance from a function by value, then you must implement a copy-constructor in the class of that instance:

**Constructors + Destructor:**

```
BitArray::BitArray()
{
    Allocate(0);
}

BitArray::~BitArray()
{
    DeallocateAll();
}

BitArray::BitArray(const BitArray& cBitArray)
{
    Allocate(0);
    *this = cBitArray;
}
```

**Assignment Operators:**

```
const BitArray& BitArray::operator=(const BitArray& cBitArray)
{
    if (this == &cBitArray)
        return *this;

    DeallocateAll();
    Allocate(cBitArray.m_Size);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m_Size; i++)
        m_Array[i] = cBitArray.m_Array[i];

    return *this;
}

const BitArray& BitArray::operator&=(const BitArray& cBitArray)
{
    return *this = *this & cBitArray;
}
```

**Binary Operators:**

```
BitArray operator&(const BitArray& cBitArray1,const BitArray& cBitArray2)
{
    if (cBitArray2.m_Size < cBitArray1.m_Size)
        return cBitArray2 & cBitArray1;

    BitArray cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cBitArray2.m_Size);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<cBitArray1.m_Size; i++)
        cRes.m_Array[i] = cBitArray1.m_Array[i] & cBitArray2.m_Array[i];
    for (; i<cBitArray2.m_Size; i++)
        cRes.m_Array[i] = cBitArray2.m_Array[i];

    return cRes;
}
```

**Internal Routines:**

```
void BitArray::Allocate(unsigned int size)
{
    m_Size = size;
    if (m_Size > 0)
        m_Array = new unsigned char[m_Size];
}

void BitArray::DeallocateAll()
{
    if (m_Size > 0)
        delete[] m_Array;
    m_Size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, don't do any of this and just use std::vector instead, which actually implemented it correctly for you.

Comment: @DeadMG: Thank you for pointing that out. I was trying to follow OP's code, which doesn't appear to be using `std::vector` (I believe that this is the case here, because otherwise, the default copy-constructor would have properly copied the `m_Array` member).

Comment: @DeadMG: Perhaps OP wishes to have more control over the memory in use. For example, in the case of a RT/embedded SW which runs over a light-weight OS, with no multi-processing, virtual memory, etc), you might wish to avoid the various memory allocations that take place every time an element is pushed into the vector. Instead, you allocate the array once, at initialization time, so that it is located at the same place in memory every time you execute your program, and as a result caching issues do not yield different performance from one execution to another.

Comment: @DeadMG: In fact, on RT/embedded SW, in many cases you would either avoid dynamic allocation altogether, or perform it once, at initialization time, before spawning the threads... So that's just one such example for why OP may have chosen not to use `std::vector`. It might not be the reason behind it, but since OP did not mention the entire system, I chose to stick with the code given at the question... By the way, since your previous comment used offensive language, I flagged it as such.